# generating basic captcha with javascript

Tags: javascript, captcha

I know catpcha and javascript dont go together but I was asked to use it..
its just something basic.. and im looking for some help with it
so I was drawing the captcha with an array of images.. and i was going to have the user enter some numbers. so if the user enters the same mumbers as the images displayed then his good to go. Here is what i got so far..

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  var images = new Array("0.jpg", "1.jpg");

  for(i=0; i<=length;i++)
  {
   var length=images.length;
  var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));
  document.write('<img src="'+images[random]+'" width = \"75\" height = \"75\"/>');
  }
```

function validate() {
    var captVAlidtion = document.getElementById("capt");

```
if (captVAlidation = "") {
alert("Please enter a phrase");    
    return false;
}
else if(captVAlidnt =0) {
    form.submit
    return true;
}
```

im stuck with the validation.. there are 5 images being displayed(ex. 0.1.2) and im wondering how to match them with the input text.. any ideas???

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but if your website is front facing, and the captcha is AT ALL important, then you should use a tried and tested one instead of cooking your own: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha

Comment: What is the point of this? How will your server know that the Captcha has been issued and validated? Any self-respecting bot will sail straight past this 'security'.

Comment: I want to protect some sensitive information on a form. I have to use captcha to help prevent scripts from attempting any hacks for which i gotta use some JavaScript to display random numbers in image form.. the user enters the numbers and i validate against the randomly generated images/numbers shown..

Comment: Im not very familiar with captchas.. I can see they arnt vey useful but I gotta use it.. did I got about it wrong on the sample??

Comment: The real problem is you can never be secure on the client's machine. If someone wanted to hack around this, they absolutely can. You only have control of your machine (ie, the server). Captchas and security in general are things that are best left to the experts, they are too easy to get wrong.

Comment: yes I can see what you say, but what im doing is not for putting live or anything like that.. if it were I would make it more secure.. I just wanted to see how to do it with the images like the sample I posted